# What is the difference between createOrReplaceTempView and pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I want to know the difference between a *pyspark dataframe* and a `createOrReplaceTempView`

I know that with *pyspark dataframe* I have to use python, and with the `createOrReplaceTempView`  it is SQL, but in terms of memory, using the cluster, parallelizing, both are the same?

For example if I use `.toPandas()` I will put all the data in memory, does something similar happends with `createOrReplaceTempView` ? or is still distributed?

Also I would like to know, if I use `CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW tablename` how do I pass this table to a pyspark dataframe

Regards

Comment: To pass the table to a pyspark dataframe, you can write the following: `df = spark.sql('SELECT * FROM tablename')`. Then df.show() will display the dataframe, df.count() will print its length, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know the difference between a pyspark dataframe and a createOrReplaceTempView

> I know that with pyspark dataframe I have to use python, and with the createOrReplaceTempView it is SQL, but in terms of memory, using the cluster, parallelizing, both are the same?

They're both should be similar

> For example if I use .toPandas() I will put all the data in memory, does something similar happends with createOrReplaceTempView ? or is still distributed?

`.toPandas()` collect all data and return to driver's memory, `createOrReplaceTempView` is lazy